# Why is my C++11 allocator's dtor called twice?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, allocator

I wrote my own basic c++11 allocator to break it down and see how it works. Things go smoothly for the most part but for some reason my dtor is called twice. This isn't a problem right now but I can imagine a scenario where a stateful allocator attempts to dereference nullptr the second time the dtor is called, so I'm curious if this is expected behavior, and if it is, is there a way to avoid it?

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<new>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using __gnu_cxx::ptrdiff_t;

template<typename elem_t>
struct myAlloc {
    typedef elem_t value_type;
    typedef elem_t * pointer;
    typedef const elem_t * const_pointer;
    typedef elem_t & reference;
    typedef const elem_t & const_reference;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    template<typename other_elem_t>
    struct rebind {
        typedef myAlloc<other_elem_t> other;
    };

    myAlloc() {
        cout << "constructing myAlloc" << endl;
    }
    ~myAlloc() {
        cout << "destructing myAlloc" << endl;
    }
    pointer address(reference x) const {
        cout << "myAlloc retrieving address" << endl;
        return &x;
    }
    const_pointer address(const_reference x) const {
        cout << "myAlloc retrieving address of x" << endl;
        return &x;
    }
    pointer allocate(size_type n, const void * hint = 0) {
        cout << "myAlloc allocating n elem_t's" << endl;
        pointer retval = (pointer)malloc(n * sizeof(value_type));

        if (retval == nullptr)
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        return retval;
    }
    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) {
        cout << "myAlloc deallocating n elem_t's" << endl;
        free(p);
    }
    size_type max_size() const throw() {
        return -1;
    }
    void construct(pointer p, const_reference val) {
        cout << "Constructing an elem_t 'val' at address p" << endl;
        new ((void*)p) value_type (val);
    }
    void destroy(pointer p) {
        cout << "Destroying the elem_t at address p" << endl;
        p->~value_type();
    }
};  

void test() {
    cout << "creating vec" << endl;
    vector<int, myAlloc<int> > myvec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    cout << "done creating vec" << endl;
}   
int main() {
    test();
    cout << "main" << endl;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
creating vec
constructing myAlloc
myAlloc allocating n elem_t's
Constructing an elem_t 'val' at address p
Constructing an elem_t 'val' at address p
Constructing an elem_t 'val' at address p
Constructing an elem_t 'val' at address p
Constructing an elem_t 'val' at address p
destructing myAlloc
done creating vec
Destroying the elem_t at address p
Destroying the elem_t at address p
Destroying the elem_t at address p
Destroying the elem_t at address p
Destroying the elem_t at address p
myAlloc deallocating n elem_t's
destructing myAlloc  
main
```

My guess is that the allocator is constructed locally whenever it's use and destructed as soon as it's done allocating the object. But then we call the `destroy` and `deallocate` functions despite the allocator being destructed. Why is it implemented this way? How it useful to destruct the allocator as soon as allocation's done? And how does calling a member function after deallocation not break things in the general case?

Comment: You forgot to instrument the copy constructor (and your allocator is also missing a converting copy constructor).

Comment: `using __gnu_cxx::ptrdiff_t;` why?

Comment: It [was copied](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79e9894990488657) internaly

Comment: @DeiDei cause without that I get an "unknown type name".  what should I use instead?

Comment: @Robert `std::ptrdiff_t` can be found in `<cstddef>`. It is standard and as such portable everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was posted in comments. Allocators are constructed twice, once for the allocation and once for the deallocation. Thanks @T.C. for the solution and @ivaigult for the implementation